# UITableView subclass init setup not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a UITableView subclass with Swift, and my values are not sticking.

I create it like this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect, style:UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        setupTableView()
    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupTableView() {
    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self
    self.bounces = false
    self.separatorStyle = .None
    self.backgroundColor = Color.lightBackground
    self.addSubview(footerImageView)
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.registerNib(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell")
}
```

When the view appears, the separators are still there, and the background is still white (`Color.lightBackground` is a light gray). I can see the tableView background, because the cells do not fill the screen. My cells do load the correct background color.

The cells do load, so I know my delegate and datasource are working.

Why do my properties not get set?

Comment: Does it still give you grief if you set the `backgroundColor` in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: This is in a tableView subclass and does not have a viewDidLoad. I don't want to have to set these values in all my controllers viewDidLoad, as that would sort of defeat the purpose.

Comment: My bad - misread what you were doing. I didn't have any issue doing the above. However, I didn't use your Color.lightBackground. Simply setting it to `orangeColor()` seemed to work. Does the table bounce, or is the separator still there?

Comment: Nope, it does not matter if I change the color. The separators are still there, and the background is still white. You did the same thing as above?

Comment: Yeah, I added a repo with my code. See if it's doing what you're intending to: https://github.com/B82607/TableViewExample

Comment: That did it..... It was my initialization process. Thank you!! Glad I am not crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same issue, and this trick helped:

```
override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.register(SearchResultCell.self,  forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchResultCell")
        self.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}
```

Honestly, I have no idea why it behaves so. But `main.async` resolves that.

Okay, I got it. The issue was caused by initializing the UITableView's subclass instance in the containing view controller's initializer.
Making the table view `lazy var` may also resolve the issue.